# Does My Answer Sound Like Product Endorsement?

Tags: discussion

I just posted an answer to a physical data security question : [How to properly secure MySQL database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30342/how-to-properly-secure-mysql-database/30381#30381)

As I stated in the question, I normally don't endorse products. Since I posted an answer based on using a product under 30-day trial which would solve the problem posed by the OP, would it still fall under the category of product endorsement? (If so, I will revoke my answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you're referencing the [faq](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) which states: (and has some links, so it's worth perusing if you're at all curious)

> ### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

However, you're not actively promoting (as far as I can tell) a product of your own, just something that you've evaluated and found to be helpful. That's like me walking into Best Buy and the guy telling me that [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) does an amazing job helping recover files on your media (it really does).

If, however, something like 40% of your posts were about "Gazzang" or a similar product, or about a loose family of related products, then we would start to wag our finger.

#### With an outstanding 30k+ rep on DBA.SE, and narry a complaint about your recommendations (is this really your first one?), and with this not being a shopping question, this is a perfectly cromulent answer.

Comment: Thank you, and +1 !!!

Answer (score 11):

To add on to Jcole's response, I think the language is important.

You are **Endorsing** a product you are unaffiliated with.  The FAQ and other policies refer to **Promoting** a product that you are in some way affiliated with.

It's perfectly fine to **endorse** a product as long as it's relevant to the question.

It's perfectly fine to **promote** a product as long as it's in moderation (not most of your answers) and it's relevant, and you disclose your affiliation with the product.

Comment: Thank you as well for chiming in, and +1 !!!

Answer (score 2):

If the product really does address the question, then there is nothing wrong with endorsing it: people are asking how you would solve a problem you are telling them (truthfully) that you would consider using that product.

If it is a product of your own or that you are otherwise closely linked to, take care to make that clear (for the avoidance of doubt) and not to fall into marketing speak (just address the question, stay relevant).

In either case if there are alternative products that you are aware of in the same area, mention them so people can easily do a little deeper research should they desire.